# Invalidate() not refreshing screen

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, invalidation

I want to make it so that pressing the screen moves my rectangle. The listener gives output to console but it doesn't invalidate the screen.

```
public class DrawView extends View{
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    static int x = 20;
    static int y = 20;

public DrawView(Context context){
    super(context);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawRect(x,y,100,100,paint);
}

public void OTListener(){
    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View DrawView, MotionEvent e){
            x = 100;
            y = 100;
            invalidate();

            return false;
        }


    });
}

}
```

Comment: What output does it give? How are you invoking this?

Comment: I don't see where you are calling `OTListener()` to call `setOnTouchListener()`. Are you calling it elsewhere or did you forget to call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It should work if it is the top view in your view hierarchy. 
You'll have to check out event.getAction() if you want to do more advanced stuff in onTouchEvent()...

```
public class DrawView extends View {

    Paint paintRect = new Paint();
    Paint paintClear = new Paint();
    private Point touch = new Point();

    public DrawView(Context context){
        super(context);
        paintClear.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paintRect.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawPaint(paintClear);
        canvas.drawRect(touch.x-50,touch.y-50,touch.x+50,touch.y+50,paintRect);
    }

    private void touch(int x, int y) {
        touch.set(x,y);          
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {       
        touch((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using invalidate() in another method doesn't work. You need to use postinvalidate() if you want to refresh activity from another method.

Comment: This is sooo wrong. Please don't proliferate false information.

Comment: @ElDuderino It would be more helpful if you would, you know, explain *Why* it is wrong and what you should do otherwise.

Comment: @ElDuderino It is how I fixed it. Submit a better answer and I will select it correct.

Comment: Ok, I did :) To comment on your answer, you are mixing some stuff. You can use invalidate only on the class view, which means in any method in the class view and from an activity if you have access to this view. You cannot call invalidate on an activity, it's not a view, but it has views. postInvalidate() is for refreshing your UI from another thread.